# Summation starting from 0

Tags: summation

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}(i) $$

This seems pretty basic, but I'm starting with the subject and the only formula I have to use for these kind of problems starts the summation at 1, like this.

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(i) $ = $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Is the same formulate valid to solve summation starting with 0? If not, how do you solve this?

Comment: What term do you include in the summation when $i = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the formula is the same, since
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} i = 0+1+\cdots+n = 0+(1+\cdots+n) = 0 + \sum_{i=1}^n i.
$$

Answer (score 5):

You're asking whether
$$
1+2+3+\cdots+n
$$
has the same value as
$$
0+1+2+3+\cdots+n
$$
And the answer is that of course those are the same.